# The type or namespace name 'Membership' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNet'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to maintain an application that contains the following line in several different files:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth;
```

I've tried everything I could find. Removed and re-added the reference; cleared the MEF cache and rebuilt; added a different file as a reference. Nothing works. It's bizarre because VS2017 doesn't report this error in the Error List window, but it does show up in the Output window. Anyway, can someone please suggest a possible solution that maybe I haven't tried yet? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to compile the project and I will describe how I got it.

1 - I delete all `using Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth;` and build project.

2 - After build the code show many errors I use the resource of VS2015 help fixes errors on code **Show potential fixes** and set again `using Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth;` build project.

3 - Set a new framework 4.6 and build project.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4aywYtmwk6lT1dDNnIxRmtQcUk

Comment: I deleted the bin folder and now I get "The type or namespace name 'AspNet' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'". Looks like I went backwards.

Comment: Close VS2017 stop the AspNet's service or reboot the windows and delete  the bin's folder. Don't open any reference service the VS2017. After this open VS2017 and build.

Comment: I think deleting the bin folder was a mistake. It blew away about half my references. I just got done adding them back in, but now I've got over 300 errors! I'm restoring from backup where I only had a few errors and will hope someone comes along with an alternate suggestion.

Comment: Just so everyone knows, I'm going to NuGet and installing "microsoft.aspnet.membership.openauth". It's spooky that this doesn't contain 'membership' in it! I'm out of ideas. Please help!

Comment: Try Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset all settings

Comment: To anyone still looking at this post, I'm dead in the water. I've been trying everything I can find, but it's all to no avail. Can someone point me to another forum where I might be able to get some help? Thanks!

Comment: Can you create a new project in VS2015? The VS2017 is brand new software and can have many bugs.

Comment: I'll try it in VS2015. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Can you provide the project to analyze myself?

Comment: Sure. Tell me what you want and how to get it to you.

Comment: Github, Google Drive, Dropbox send me the link.